# Как получить все элементы без пары с bitwise xor?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, битовые-операции, xor

Как адаптировать данный код что бы ***он выводил все числа без пары***:

```
const array = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9]

console.log(array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc ^ cur, 0))
```

сейчас он работает нормально **для одного числа** и выводит 8 (что верно), потому что у этого числа нет пары как у остальных (1 и 1, 3 и 3, и так далее). Как доработать даную логику xor для того что бы получать все числа без пары из исходного массива в новый массив **используя логику с xor выше**?

Исходный массив `[1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9, 7]`

Результат `[8, 7]`

Comment: А вот это уже так не работает... Сортируйте и попарно удаляйте.

Comment: @Harry Может всетаки как то можно? Я в целом не очень разобралась как работает xor в этом случае, он постоянно плюсует или заменяет основное значение целиком?

Comment: xor "сокращает" пару, но для нескольких значений без пары вы получите одно значение, из которого выковырять, сколько и каких значений было без пары - не получится. для вашего набора вы получите 8 xor 7 = 15, а дальше - как вы отличите - это 8 и 7 или 3 и 12 или просто 15?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю, можно ли с xor, но без него и без сортировки можно так:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9, 7];

const singles = [...arr.reduce(
  (acc, element) => {
    if (acc.has(element)) acc.delete(element);
    else acc.add(element);
    return acc;
  },
  new Set(),
)];

console.log(singles);
```

Или чуть короче и чуть менее ясно:

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 3, 1, 8, 9, 9, 7];

const singles = [...arr.reduce(
  (acc, element) => acc.delete(element) ? acc : acc.add(element),
  new Set(),
)];

console.log(singles);
```

Comment: Как С++'ник, не разберающийся в JS - какая эффективность данного кода? O(NlgN)? O(N^2)?

Comment: Мне трудно сказать. Если не ошибаюсь, Set, как и Map, как и объекты, использует хеш-функции для доступа к элементам. Поэтому удаление и добавление у этих структур должно иметь соразмеримую эффективность. Наверное, нужно тестировать, будет ли это для больших массивов эффективно. Но другой выход, наверное, только с сортировкой, и тут опять нужно будет сравнивать, не уравняют ли затраты на сортировку эффективность.

Comment: Вот про реализацию Map, оригинал и перевод. У Set по идее та же механика под капотом: https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-map-internals-45eb94a183df и https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/518032/

Comment: Там ещё говорится о накладных расходах на перестройку таблиц при удалении и добавлении, что в нашем случае будет ощутимо. Но в большинстве случаев, при равномерном распределении дубликатов, вряд ли структура будет успевать вырасти, чтобы эти затраты стали очень большими. Хотя из меня тут не ахти какой специалист)

Comment: Вот тут можно посмотреть приблизительную эффективность для структур с хеш-таблицами в JS, вроде обнадёживает: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms#data-structure-operations-complexity